EF Core 8: How can I model a m:n relationship on two tables with the same column of a third table?
How do I model the relationship between the table User2Group and Tenant2Group correctely?

For now I have
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Group> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("groups");

        builder.HasKey(group => group.Id);

        builder.Property(group => group.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);

        builder.Property(group => group.DefaultGroupForTenantId).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(25);

        builder.Property<byte[]>("version").IsRowVersion().HasColumnName("version");

        builder
            .HasMany(e => e.Users2Groups)
            .WithOne(e => e.Group)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.GroupId)
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .HasMany(e => e.Tenants2Groups)
            .WithOne(e => e.Group)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.TenantId)
            .IsRequired();
    }

When I try to run the query
        var users = _dbContext.Users
            .Where(u => u.IdentityId == identityId)
            .Include(u => u.Users2Groups)
            .ThenInclude(g => g.Tenants2Groups)
            .ThenInclude(t2G => t2G.Tenant)
            .ToList();

VS issues the query can contain incomplete data and I should use User2Group.Group as shown here:
        var users = _dbContext.Users
            .Where(u => u.IdentityId == identityId)
            .Include(u => u.Users2Groups)
            .ThenInclude(u2G => u2G.Group)
            .ThenInclude(g => g.Tenants2Groups)
            .ThenInclude(t2G => t2G.Tenant)
            .ToList();

How can I avoid that and use the shorter version without including group?
